# Ruby: read file byte-wise

Tags: ruby

I'm absolutely new to Ruby having just read some tutorials. It looks like I can read the file content as

```
svg = File.read(path)
```

Now it looks like the file content is treated as a string and regular expression replace is used:

```
svg = svg.gsub(/(width|height)="\d+px"/, '')
```

How to define the encoding to use the text file? How to read the file contents into a byte array (leaving the regular expression aside)?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: "how to read the file byte-wise" - not sure what exactly what you mean here, but JFYI, doing regex replace on byte streams is... quite difficult, to put it mildly. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`File#open`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-open). Rather than returning a string, this gives you an IO object on which you can call methods such as [`each_byte`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-each_byte). You can also pass `open` arguments specifying the encoding.

Comment: For what method I can provide the `open` arguments? For `File.read(path)` or for `File.open(path)`, too?

Comment: Check the docs. Looks like `File.read` is actually mixed in from `IO.read` which accepts the same kinds of encoding arguments.